Django-formwizard with dynamically generated Formset not submitting
I'm trying to get django-formwizard to work with dynamically generated formset of the users' input in the first form.
The forms render and initial data shows up fine, but when I try to submit the 2nd form, I get it back without errors and I do not proceed to the done() method.
My forms:
class MenuInputForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField()


class DayMenuForm(forms.Form):
    menu = forms.CharField()


DayMenuFormSet = formset_factory(form=DayMenuForm, min_num=1, extra=0)

My views:
class MenuAddWizard(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):

    # Either provide form_list as part of .as_view() in urls, or here.
    # Note: DayMenuFormSet is overwritten in get_form()
    form_list = [MenuInputForm, DayMenuFormSet]
    template_name = "menu_add.html"

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super().get_form(step, data, files)

        # Determine the step if not given
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current

        if step == '1':
            step_0_cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
            # Using step 0 data, I generate the list to be used for initial; removing logic for brevity and using two example items as test
    
            DayMenuFormSet = formset_factory(form=DayMenuForm, extra=0)
            formset = DayMenuFormSet(initial=[{'menu': 'Some example menu'}, {'menu': 'This is some other example text'}])
            form = formset

        return form

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        # This code is never reached, whatever I put here (redirect, print, ...)
        pass

Template:
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<table>
    {{ wizard.management_form }}

    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

What am I doing wrong or forgetting about?

Could it simply be that .done() returns nothing? Normally, you should render a template or even better, redirect to a view.
Update:
I now see you're not passing any data to the formset in get_form(). Therefore, the form is never validated, and no errors are shown because the form thinks no data was submitted.
So change this line
formset = DayMenuFormSet(initial=[{'menu': 'Some example menu'}, {'menu': 'This is some other example text'}])

to
formset = DayMenuFormSet(
    initial=[{'menu': 'Some example menu'}, {'menu': 'This is some other example text'}], 
    data=data    # <- You forgot about this.

)

Well, I do have something in the done() function (such as redirects) but that was omitted for brevity. The problem is that I do not get to done() - any code I put in there isn't executed.

Bedankt Mathieu, forgot about adding data=data to the formset, indeed!
